# unwanted patterns in simplex noise

Tags: noise

I want to create a "river biome" where there are rivers cutting to a flat land mass, to start I wrote a little js to generate a random height map (with simplex noise) but that's where I'm stuck.

this is what it generates:
[image]

as you can see there are clear diagonal lines in there.
I tried looking up how to fix this and on my search I found these:

- [Is all grid based noise inevitably anisotropic?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-all-grid-based-noise-inevitably-anisotropic)
- [Why does my Perlin Noise look "blocky"?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/why-does-my-perlin-noise-look-blocky)

I don't know if this is my problem of if it's something else entirely.

here's the significant part of my code:

```
for(var y = 0;y < myRivers.height;y++){
    for(var x = 0;x < myRivers.width;x++){
        lightness = simplexnoise(x/50,y/50); // number between -1 and 1
        myRivers.context.fillStyle = lightnessToRgb(lightness); //maps lightness to a color
        myRivers.context.fillRect(x * 4, y * 4, 4, 4); // fills a pixel with the color
    }
}
```

a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gooyMj

Comment: The second question you link to has a good analysis. What happens when you look at just 1 octave of the noise? Also, what interpolation function are you using? Linear interp will look more blocky than using a smooth step, for example.

Comment: I don’t really use interpolation I think

Comment: @user1118321 so multiplying with another octave might work?

Comment: A heightmap generated from Perlin noise won't give you a plausible-looking river system anyway. Rivers "cut" their own valleys through terrain.

Comment: @DanHulme I’m talking about a flat land mass so it wouldn’t look like normal rivers anyway

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting a solution. I'm suggesting a way of determining what the problem is. If you show just your lowest octave, what does it look like? Is it blocky? I don't enough about how the `simplexnoise()` function you're using works to tell you. Is that a function you wrote or something supplied by a library?

Comment: Shader toy has a simplex noise implementation that you can edit in real time [here](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Msf3WH) This is a good place to compare your implementation and play with different values to see what results simplex noise will give. (and look at some other examples of simplex in action)

Answer (score 1):

I know im a bit late, but hopefully this can help other people. you can add detail by using Fractal Brownian Motion. There is a great article [here](https://cmaher.github.io/posts/working-with-simplex-noise/) that i used as a guide to make my own version in c#. Also I would check to make sure your vars are ints.